# How do you generate data that can be used for a binomial family stan_glmer model with random effects?

Tags: sampling, stan

I am wondering how I can generate binomial sample data that can be used for a stan_glmer random effects model. For example, is this a correct example?

`Y <- rbinom(10, 1, inv.logit(X))`

where

`X <- rnorm(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this from time to time.

In the mixed effects literature, the linear predictor is written as

$$ \eta = X\beta + Z\gamma $$

Here, I've assumed a random intercept, so the $Z\gamma$ really affects the $\beta_0$ in the model.  Here is how I code up my random effects simulations

```r
#Generate covariates and model matrix.
n=100
p=3
X = matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow = n)
X[,1] = 1

#Generate subjects.  Remove the intercept from Z
subjects = 1:10
observed_subjects = factor(sample(subjects, size = n, replace = T))
Z = model.matrix(~observed_subjects -1)

#coefficients and random effects
beta = c(-0.2, 0.1, 0.03)
gamma = rnorm(length(subjects), 0, 0.2)

#Linear predictor
eta = X %*% beta + Z %*% gamma

#Convert to probabilities
p = plogis(eta)

# Now generate data
y = rbinom(n,1,p)
```

You should be able to make a dataframe out of `X`, `y`, and `observed_subjects` now and pass that to `stan_glmer`.

Comment: Thanks, so the call will be `stan_glmer(y ~ eta + (1|observed_subjects))`?

Comment: Well, no.  You have to put the data into a data frame.  The call would be `stan_glmer(y~ X1 + X2 + (1|subjects), data = d, family = binomial)`.  It depends on what you call the covariates and the subject identifier.